Facing issue with the "sudo gedit" command on Ubuntu 22.04
I am always getting this crash window when I am using the sudo gedit command:

I wanted to edit the waffle.yaml file for a ROS2 project.
I am facing the same issue for any other file which I am opening using the same command.
I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 on Oracle VM VirtualBox.

This question is similar to: Cannot open display error when I run sudo gedit on Ubuntu 14.04.5. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

try ''sudo -E gedit waffle.yaml''

Rather than sudo gedit, set up the EDITOR and VISUAL environment variables in your ~/.bashrc:
export EDITOR=$(type -p gedit)
export VISUAL=$(type -p gedit)

Then, sudoedit waffle.yaml.
sudoedit works like this:

As root, sudoedit makes a temporary copy of the file.
As $USER, sudoedit invokes your editor on the temporary file, avoiding any problems with Graphical editor as root.
As root, if the file was changed, and the editor exited successfully, sudoedit copies the temporary file back.

